# Operator Overload "new" C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, operator-keyword

I used this operator overload in the class Base:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t sz1) {
//Se llama a la funcion de xMemoryManager
// std::printf("global op new called, size = %zu\n",sz);
cout<<"operador new"<<endl;
```

}

But i am inheriting from Base class to Derived class, and i have this code in Derived class:

```
xPointer<Pruebas> *xPruebas;
xPruebas=new xPointer<Pruebas>;
xPointer<Pruebas> *xPruebas1;
xPruebas1=new xPointer<Pruebas>;
```

Well, in this lines i need to use the primitive operator new, not the overload operator of the Base class.

How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Write an `operator new` for the derived class and in it call `::operator new`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have overriding `operator new` functions in the derived class. Here are two strategies that I was able to think of. The program below shows how to use them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct Base
{
   void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
   {
      return malloc(sz);
   }
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
   // Simple override.
   void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
   {
      return ::operator new(sz);
   }
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
   // Can be used as placement new.
   void* operator new(std::size_t sz, void* p)
   {
      return p;
   }
};

int main()
{
   // Use operator new in the basic form.
   Derived1* ptr1 = new Derived1;
   std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl;

   // Use operator new in the placement new form.
   // Allocate memory for the object first using global operator new.
   // Then call the placement new.
   void* p = ::operator new(sizeof(Derived2));
   Derived2* ptr2 = new (p) Derived2;
   std::cout << ptr2 << std::endl;
}
```